# What is the most efficient, quickest, lightest way to check if a SharePoint list exists in a SSO/MFA environment?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, sso, multifactor-authentication

Something that retrieves the whole list is the worst answer.
Something that comes back with a binary true would be the best.

The only way I can see how to do it currently involves pulling back masses of uneccessary data from the site(s).

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Find a list by Title**
It's not ideal, but you can check if the list exists using this REST query:

```
https://YOUR_SITE/_api/Web/Lists/?$filter=Title eq 'Documents'
```

It does return some metadata, but with no list items.
You can reduce the amout of metadata you get by adding this header to your request:

```
accept: application/json; odata=minimalmetadata
```

**Option 2. Send GET request using list URL**

Send a GET request directly to the list URL

If you know a library/list URL, you can send a GET request to this URL. For example

```
https://YOUR_SITE/Library_THAT_DOES_NOT_EXIST
```

This will return a 404 status. It means that the list does not exist.

If you send a GET request to the library/list that exists, you will get 2** response, meaning it exists

```
https://YOUR_SITE/Shared Documents
```

Comment: Thanks... I have tried those. The problem is I cannot find a way to do that in PowerQuery.
Option 1: I don;t think those Custom Headers are on the WhiteList inPowerQuery
Option 2: the REST endpoint doesn't return error codes like that (SharePoint)

Comment: PowerQuery? that totally changes the question. In this case, no, I don't think there is a "binary" way you can use there to determine if a list exists or not. At least I don't know how to do it.

Comment: That's what I feared.